# Sharing data between neo4j and elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and elastic search. I've been playing around these 2 and now have a use case wherein I need to integrate both. Since I know that the elastic search and neo4j stores data separately, the data would be duplicated. Is there anyway to share data between these 2? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the data duplication? Meaning that you could access stored information from elasticsearch through neo4j without redundancy?

Comment: @Cheffe Thanks for your reply. Yes that is correct. I've a use case wherein I've to do a fuzzy/full text search on the data and also store the data in a graph database such that I can get the relationship out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Neo4j is a graph database, Lucene is an inverted search index.  They do not function on the same principles and can not function on the same stored data representation.  Duplicating data is to be expected, though.  Even defining an index through your database schema is going to result in some data duplication.

If you aren't so much concerned with duplicating the data on disk, and more with how to keep them synced up, it's not unusual to have a database feed a lucene search index.  Neo4j doesn't have anything built in to handle elasticsearch, but this [neo4j-elasticsearch river](https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j) seems a promising possibility.

Neo4j does have some [legacy support for lucene indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html), though I'd be rather inclined to do as neo4j recommends, and define indexes in the DB schema, rather than relying on legacy systems.